# Get SAS working on a probe in KSP 0.90?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In KSP 0.90 (beta), command pods only provide [SAS](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Stability_Augmentation_System) when a pilot is onboard. A probe command pod like the [Stayputnik](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Stayputnik_Mk._1) doesn't have a pilot aboard. I tried adding an [SAS module](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Small_Inline_Reaction_Wheel) to my Stayputnik probes, but this doesn't enable SAS. How does one get SAS working with a probe in KSP 0.90?

There's a similar but obsolete question about SAS on piloted vessels in a much earlier version of KSP. [How to get SAS working in Kerbal Space Program](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/123404/93658)

Comment: Maneuvering without SAS is less hard if you CAPS LOCK to switch between raw and fine steering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The inline reaction wheels provide rotation torque, but no automatic SAS functionality. This feature now has to be provided by the probe core itself. The Stayputnik as the most basic probe core doesn't have SAS capabilities. The first probe core which provides SAS is the **Probodobodyne OKTO**.

On a manned ship, you can get SAS capabilities by having a kerbal with the Pilot class on board.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea why my second rocket couldn't SAS.

Comment: It may be worth noting that more advanced probe cores offer more of the new SAS features (like prograde/retrograde hold, target alignment, etc.).